# Add multiple result of case when mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT queueposition, byusername, targetLanguage, bycountry, targetInterest, targetCodePostal, targetGenders, timestamp, checkedZip, ageIdeal, 
                CASE WHEN targetLanguage = '".$language."' THEN 4.0 ELSE 0 END
              + CASE WHEN targetLanguage = '".$language2."' THEN 3.0 ELSE 0 END
              + CASE WHEN bycountry = '".$countryCode."' THEN 2.0 ELSE 0 END
              + CASE WHEN checkedZip = '".$codePostal."' THEN 5.0 ELSE 0 END
              + CASE WHEN byusername != '".$_SESSION['username']."' THEN -500.0 ELSE 0 END
              + CASE WHEN ageIdeal >= $ageUserLess10 AND ageIdeal <= $ageUserMore10 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END
                END AS SumWeights

                FROM queueTimelight
                WHERE alreadyViewed = 'no' AND statusModeration = 'Approved'
                ORDER BY SumWeights
```

How can I have the sum of all THENs in SumWeights instead of having a single result?

Desired Output :

- I want if the first case and the second case is true, so the
  SumWeights will be 4.0 + 3.0 = 7.0

Comment: Provide some data samples and desired results will help us help you but look into Sub selects maybe?  But sample data will help

Comment: Each of the six conditions is it's own `CASE` expression, with an `ELSE 0`, and then add them together.

Comment: How can i add them together ?

Comment: also this line never executes `WHEN targetLanguage = $var THEN 3.0`

Comment: I update with the right data

Comment: you updated your question with the answer , you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Ok it's done now

Comment: *I want if the first case and the second case is true....* how can a column's value be equal ro '".$language2."' and '".$language."' at the same time?

Comment: Indeed, I meant if it's one or the other, but I would have done better to use a gold in this case, thanks for the remark

Comment: Yikes, this looks crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear to me what you want, but maybe this will work for you:

```
SELECT queueposition, byusername, targetLanguage, bycountry, targetInterest, targetCodePostal, targetGenders, timestamp, checkedZip, ageIdeal, 
          CASE WHEN targetLanguage = $var THEN 4.0 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN targetLanguage = $var THEN 3.0 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN bycountry = $var THEN 2.0 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN checkedZip = $var THEN 5.0 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN byusername != $var THEN -500.0 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN ageIdeal >= $var AND ageIdeal <= $var THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END 
   AS SumWeights
FROM `table`
WHERE statusModeration = 'Approved'
ORDER BY SumWeights
```

Also, that has the same `targetLanguage = $var` condition twice. Maybe you wanted something else there.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work i have a syntax error

Comment: @Meds its only there is an extra end ,

Comment: Oh sorry my bad ! Yes it's work now thank's !